# Delegating vim filetype after removing suffix

Tags: vim

I know how to configure vim to select a particular filetype based upon an extension:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.foo set filetype=foo
```

However, a common case for me is to wind up opening a file with an additional suffix.  One specific scenario is resolving version control conflicts during a merge.  I'll have up files like "foo.cpp.orig" or "foo.java.merge", etc.  I'd like to configure vim so that if it opens a file ending in ".orig", etc. for it to strip that suffix and use remaining file extension to select the filetype.

And yes, I do know I could do something like

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.java.* set filetype=java
```

But that is less than ideal because I have to manually add an entry for all the possible filetypes I might be editing.

Comment: when `:filetype` has `detection:ON`, vim still has problem to detect the correct type?

Comment: Yes. Just to be sure I checked and :filetype tells me

     detection:ON plugin:ON indent:ON

Comment: see my answer, the author seems already considered it. you might need to make some adjustment for your situation.

Comment: Adding all those lines to your vimrc would have been quicker and simpler than typing this question.

Comment: I guess you have a mistaken impression of just how many different file types I edit if you think adding lines for each is efficient.  The question was about solving the problem the correct way, not the dumb brute force way.

Answer (score 2):

```
" Ignored extensions
if exists("*fnameescape")
au BufNewFile,BufRead ?\+.orig,?\+.bak,?\+.old,?\+.new,?\+.dpkg-dist,?\+.dpkg-old,?\+.dpkg-new,?\+.dpkg-bak,?\+.rpmsave,?\+.rpmnew
        \ exe "doau filetypedetect BufRead " . fnameescape(expand("<afile>:r"))
au BufNewFile,BufRead *~
        \ let s:name = expand("<afile>") |
        \ let s:short = substitute(s:name, '\~$', '', '') |
        \ if s:name != s:short && s:short != "" |
        \   exe "doau filetypedetect BufRead " . fnameescape(s:short) |
        \ endif |
        \ unlet! s:name s:short
au BufNewFile,BufRead ?\+.in
        \ if expand("<afile>:t") != "configure.in" |
        \   exe "doau filetypedetect BufRead " . fnameescape(expand("<afile>:r")) |
        \ endif
elseif &verbose > 0
  echomsg "Warning: some filetypes will not be recognized because this version of Vim does not have fnameescape()"
endif
```

actually, Vim already considered it. the above code is from `filetype.vim`

Comment: Ah, I hadn't actually tried .orig first, because I had assumed when it failed on .merge that it didn't handle it at all.  So that is good to know, but doesn't really give me a way to extend the set of suffixes it knows about.

Comment: patch `filetype.vim` or rename your backup file then :)

Comment: That's a pretty substandard solution.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at the code Dyno pointed me to, I think what I want is to add

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead ?\+.merge
        \ exe "doau filetypedetect BufRead " . fnameescape(expand("<afile>:r"))
```

to my .vimrc.  It isn't quite as nice as having some variable to set to extend the list of known patterns, but isn't as much of a hack as modifying the original filetype.vim.